# How to add up a single class across an entire website and apply it to a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have a website that has the class ".post" on multiple pages. I need to add up the total amount of times ".post" appears on this website -- across all pages -- and apply that sum to a variable.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $.get('www.website.com', function(data){ 
        var count = $(data).find(".post").length;
        alert(count);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Firstly, you haven't actually asked a question here. Secondly, it sounds like you need a loop.

Comment: Converted to question!

Comment: Is it there another api i.e. `/blogs`? to get all blog

Comment: @Satpal, /blog would be the main page, with /blog/1, /blog/2 being additional pages.

Comment: does it sequential?

Comment: @Chay22 Yes, it's sequential.

Comment: @Weebs what do you want to do? extract the number of the url?

Comment: @claudio To sum it up, I want to count all the ".post" classes on "/blog" and its subsequent pages (e.g., /blog/1, /blog/2) and apply that total count to a variable.

Comment: do you aware of each url you're going to get or at least total of blogs, since its sequential?

Comment: @Chay22 The total number of blog pages will be unknown, but will be 1 or greater.

Comment: can you provide your url which you are using @Weebs

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following approach, please be aware that it might contain errors since I was not able to test it. The main idea is to have a function get and count the number of matches recursively until an errors occurs, which means that if the pages aren't sequential it wont work.

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    var count = 0,
        maxErrors = 5,
        selector = '.post';

    function countElements(selector, page, onEnd)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '/blog/' + page,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                count += $(data).find(selector).length;
                console.log('Page ' + page + ' current count ' + count);
                countElements(selector, page + 1, onEnd); // recursion, load next page
            },
            error: function() {
                maxErrors--;
                if (maxErrors < 0) {
                    onEnd(count, page);
                } else {
                    countElements(selector, page + 1, onEnd); // recursion, load next page
                }
            }
        });
    }

    countElements(selector, 1, function(total, pages) {
        alert('There is a total of ' + total + ' (' + selector + ') on ' + pages + ' pages');
    }); //start on page 1
 });
```

Comment: If you're going this way, you could allow room to skip one. It's not unthinkable that one item gets deleted, a simple check to continue one try more wont hurt much and might recover a whole lot more data :)

Comment: Thanks, @claudio, but it's not picking up any elements with a ".post" class. It just shows "0".

Comment: @Martijn just added the errors part.

Comment: @Weebs what is being logged on the console?

Comment: @claudio Here's what's on the console: (index):339 Uncaught TypeError: onEnd is not a function
    at Object.error ((index):339)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at T (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @Weebs I had forgotten to pass the onEnd parameter, just edited the code

Answer (score 0):

You can crawl via AJAX and increment and see which all exists, but this will get very, very slow. If you take 1 second per request, and check for 50 blogs (wether they exists or not), that will take at least 50 seconds.

Check if there is a sitemap containing the urls to the blogs, often one exists (you can try */sitemap*, */sitemap.php or* */sitemap.xml*). That way, you only have to fetch relevant pages, not abusing resources which saves you time and effort.

Then, I suggest you do this with PHP or a serverside language. Those can be optimised beter and work from the network of the server, instead of your local connection. For each page, store the result (either the html or the count you're looking for). Now next run, you dont have to do them all again, just continue where you were, saving huge amounts of time.